# Facebook page access token broken after adding new permissions to user token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Based on the [doc on Facebook page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) following steps are need to be taken to obtain a long-lived Page Access Token.

1. Extend the User's Access Token which has the manage_pages permissions
2. Get the page access token thru the /userId/accounts end point using the extended user access token.

This process is working fine and I am able to obtain and use the page access token properly.

The issue arises when the user grants a new permission to the App - such as 'publish_actions' to allow the App to post on the Page's timeline, the page access token obtained using the above mentioned mechanism does not work properly.

Until about a 6 to 8 weeks ago the new publish_action permission would allow the previously saved page access token to post on the page's timeline without any issue. This feature seems to have broken where I am getting the following error :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200
```

When the access token is debuged using the Facebook debugger tool - it shows that the saved page access token is indeed embellished with the new permission as follows :

```
App ID  XXXXXXXXXXXX : App Name
Profile ID  999999999999 : Page Name
User ID  9999999999999999 : User Name
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  1454463877 (40 minutes ago)
Expires Never
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  email, manage_pages, publish_actions, public_profile
```

So although this page token has publish_actions permission it is not able to post on the page's timeline. This has stopped working recently and looking for any other folks who have faced a similar issue and have managed to resolve it.

Btw, I have already tried refreshing the page access token using the newly generated user access_token at the time when the user gives the publish_actions permission. Going the thru the above 2 steps using the new user access token, seem to return the same page access token and it continues to fail to post on timeline...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a case of just refreshing the pages access token, when a user adds a new permission it will completely change their token. You will need to first off extend the users access token (with the new permission) and then make a request to `/me/accounts` to get the new page access token.

Comment: I have added an answer to this question - which is how we resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to using incorrect permission. Facebook has introduced a new 'Publish_pages' permission which should be used to make posts on  business pages. We were using publish_action which was invalid (since v2.3 or somewhere around that - we are using v2.5 of the graph API so it caused a problem).

Facebook responded pretty quickly to our bug report and provided this guidance which helped resolve this issue (I should have posted this answer earlier).